# Why my regex not working for char validation

Tags: python, regex

Here my `(?=.*[a-z]{2})` is explicitly checking for explicitly 2 small chars. but could not taking it

```
import re
char = 'Massas23#'
if re.search(r"^(?=.*[\d])(?=.*[A-Z])(?=.*[a-z]{2})(?=.*[@#$])[\w\d@#$]{6,12}$", char):
    print ("match")
else:
    print ("Not Match")
```

My out is `Match` and Expected is `Not Match`

Comment: not more than 2 smaller case, explicitly 2 small case

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Maybe,

```
^(?!.*[a-z]{3})(?=.*[\d])(?=.*[A-Z])(?=.*[a-z]{2})(?=.*[@#$])[\w\d@#$]{6,12}$
```

might work then.

```
(?!.*[a-z]{3})
```

means more than three consecutive lowercases are not allowed.

#### [Demo 1](https://regex101.com/r/0H1bdA/1/)

#### Test

```
import re

char = 'Massas23#'

if re.search(r"^(?!.*[a-z]{3})(?=.*[\d])(?=.*[A-Z])(?=.*[a-z]{2})(?=.*[@#$])[\w\d@#$]{6,12}$", char):
    print("match")
else:
    print("Not Match")
```

---

If you wish to simplify/modify/explore the expression, it's been explained on the top right panel of [regex101.com](https://regex101.com/r/0H1bdA/1/). If you'd like, you can also watch in [this link](https://regex101.com/r/0H1bdA/1/debugger), how it would match against some sample inputs.

---

#### RegEx Circuit

[jex.im](https://jex.im/regulex/#!flags=&re=%5E(a%7Cb)*%3F%24) visualizes regular expressions:

[image]

---

I guess we were not trying to match `MAsSa23#`, if you wish to match that,

```
^(?!.*[a-z]{3})(?=.*[\d])(?=.*[A-Z])(?=.*[a-z]{1,2})(?=.*[@#$])[\w\d@#$]{6,12}$
```

would do that.

#### [Demo 2](https://regex101.com/r/eDLTR1/1/)

Comment: why you put `(?!.*[a-z]{3})` in the begning

Comment: It does not match `MAsSa23#` which I think it should `explicitly 2 small case`

Answer (score 0):

You could omit the lowercase chars from the character class and then match exactly 2 lowercase chars a-z.

You can make use of [contrast](https://www.rexegg.com/regex-style.html#contrast) using negated character classes for example matching not a digit.

```
^(?=.{6,12}$)(?=[^\d\s]*\d)(?=[^A-Z\s]*[A-Z])(?=[^@#$\s]*[@#$])[A-Z0-9_@#$]*[a-z][A-Z0-9_@#$]*[a-z][A-Z0-9_@#$]*$
```

- `^` Start of string
- `(?=.{6,12}$)` Assert 6 - 12 chars
- `(?=[^\d\s]*\d)` Assert a digit
- `(?=[^A-Z\s]*[A-Z])` Assert an uppercase char
- `(?=[^@#$\s]*[@#$])` Assert a special char
- `[A-Z0-9_@#$]*[a-z][A-Z0-9_@#$]*[a-z][A-Z0-9_@#$]*` Match 2 lowercase a-z
- `$` End of string

[Regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/EpMMog/1)

Note that

- `[\d]` does not have to be between square brackets
- `[\w\d@#$]` `\w` also matches `\d` so that can be omitted from the character class